# How to block brute force attempts on a login-service/application gateway?

Tags: node.js, security, express, brute-force

I am having a thin gateway/portal application based on `Node.js` and `express`. It is managing sessions, user authentication and routing (to the actual application).

According to https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet#Session_ID_Guessing_and_Brute_Force_Detection it is recommended to block IP-adresses once *the application* detects multiple failed login attempts in a given period.

Now I am having 2 questions:

1) In what part of the infrastructure should those IP-Adresses be blocked? What will be best practice in this department?

- Node.js application (which will leave the overall application affected by brutefoce/DoS attacks)
- Some webserver(?) installed 'in front of' the `Node.js` application?
- A dedicated proxy-server installed 'in front of' the `Node.js` application?
- In the firewall itself, in case the firewall will have such a feature?
- Anything else?

2) In case it should be handled directly in the `Node.js` application, how would I go about blocking IP-adresses in the most efficient way (technically/in code)? I would imagine that brute force attacks will still cause load on the process if I just check this kind of brute-forcing in my normal `express` request handler?

To clarify, the application is reachable through internet as well as intranet (thousands of users).

Comment: To me, it seems very clear that any web application needs to be protected using accepted security methodologies. It doesn't matter that this is a Node application. It could be a PHP or .NET application. There is nothing "PHP specific" or ".NET specific" or "Node specific" to security implementations. Your best course is to hire a firm specializing in web security issues.

Comment: I was not especially referring to a *Node.js* application, you can read it more like "**the application**". My concerns are more related to whether something should be done in **the application**, or outside of it (if so, where?)